# PHPUnit Testing Exceptions for Laravel Resource Controllers

Tags: unit-testing, exception, laravel, phpunit

Is it possible to test Exceptions with Laravel resource controllers? Every time I try to do the following:

```
/**
 * @expectedException Exception
 * @expectedExceptionMessage Just testing this out
 */
public function testMyPost() {
    $response = $this->call('POST', '/api/myapi/', array('testing' => 1));
}
```

I get:

```
Failed asserting that exception of type "Exception" is thrown.
```

I've tried this with **\Exception** and **Exception**.

In my resource controller I have:

```
public function store() {
    throw new \Exception('Just for testing!');
}
```

Does anyone has any idea of I can test Exceptions? I've also tried using:

```
    $this->setExpectedException('InvalidArgumentException');
```

Comment: what if you specify it as `@expectedException \\Exception`  ?

Comment: Same :( Failed asserting that exception of type "\\Exception" is thrown.

Comment: What if you wrap your call with `try-catch` and get the exact type of exception with `get_class($e)`? Presumably it's `$this->call()` what throws an exception, and your original exception is handled by something else.

Comment: Nothing is thrown.. even if I call `$response = $this->action('POST', 'APIController@store');`, nothing seems to be thrown.

Comment: what if you send `POST` with `curl` and see what is actually returned to you?

Comment: Laravel is probably catching it in its default error handler in `app/start/global.php`.

Comment: It's weird, even though I remove the App::error from the global file (for testing) I still don't get the exceptions, oh well.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is as hannesvdvreken states; the exception is caught. An easy work-around is to tell Laravels errort/exception handler, that when we are testing, we just want our exceptions thrown.

That could look something like this:

```
    // If we are testing, just throw the exception.
    if (App::environment() == 'testing') {
        throw $e;
    }
```

For Laravel 5, this should go in the render method in app/Exceptions/Handler.php

For Laravel 4, this should go in app/start/global.php within:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)...
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't focus on the notation of `@expectedException`. The problem is the Exception is catched somewhere. Maybe with the default `App::error(function(Exception) {...` inside the `app/start/global.php` file.

Or maybe you did a try catch somewhere. Try making a custom Exception that does not get catched by a generic exception catcher that catches everything that's inherited from Exception.

Comment: I'll try the custom Exception and let you know. But, at the end of the day I'll will want to catch the Exceptions so my application doesn't break, but if I do that, then the Unit testing will not work :(