# UnauthorizedException not caught with Laravel 5 / Codeception

Tags: laravel, exception, phpunit, codeception

I'm trying to intercept a UnauthorizedException with Codeception in my functional test. Well, In fact my functional test are Laravel tests triggered by codeception. So, I tried 2 ways:

```
/** @test
 *
 * @expectedException UnauthorizedException
 */
public function test_exception()
{

    $this->visit("/associations/1/edit")

}
```

Or

```
 /** @test
 *
 */
public function test_exception()
{
   \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::setExpectedException(UnauthorizedException::class);
    $this->visit("/associations/1/edit")

}
```

In my controller, I just trow it to test:

```
 throw new UnauthorizedException();
```

In both cases, it just says:

```
Failed asserting that exception of type "UnauthorizedException" is thrown.
```

Everything seems fine, but it doesn't seem to work... Any idea why???

EDIT : My Edit Method in Controller

```
public function edit($id)
{

    $association = Association::findOrFail($id);
    $federation = $association->federation;

    if (Auth::user()->cannot('edit', $association)) { // I have checked with dd() my test goes here.
        throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }

    $users = User::all();
    $federations = Federation::all();

    return view('associations.form', compact('association', 'users', 'federations', 'federation'));
}
```

Comment: tried namespacing? `\Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\UnauthorizedException`

Comment: I use : use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\UnauthorizedException; shoudn't it be the same thing?

Comment: Yes it should. Can you post the full controller method

Comment: which one???? edit or update?

Comment: The one that throws the exception

Comment: well, as I am testing, the first line is throwing an exception, this is not the normal behaviour, but, for now, I can't even make it work like that

Comment: Still, I can publish the whole method, no pb, it is not big

Comment: Please post the full method anyways. It helps others re construct your train of thought and can help narrow down the issues

Comment: can you try this instead of throwing the exception? `abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');`

Comment: I can try it, but AFAIK, abort will always throw a HttpException

Comment: you're probably right. Ill test it on my end aswell , try updating the test case aswell to see if it catches the HTTPException

Comment: Yep, it catches an HttpException, confirmed

Comment: Interesting. I will keep debugging.

Comment: yep, it's the first time I try to catch exception in my tests, so I don't know what's wrong... I can confirm both phpunit and codeception react the same way

Comment: Probably not the reason but can you try passing it a message: `throw new UnauthorizedException("not authorized");`

Comment: yep, did it, but had no effect

Comment: Look at this article: https://laraveltips.wordpress.com/category/handling-exceptions-and-custom-exceptions-laravel-5-1/ It might have to do with how Laravel handles exceptions

Comment: In fact, this is the article I used to use exceptions in my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207807/phpunit-testing-exceptions-for-laravel-resource-controllers):

Basic idea, I guess, is exception is catched and sent to Handler where a view is returned.

So, for testing, you should include in Handler.php the condition:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if (App::environment() == 'testing') {
        throw $e;
    }
    // Your exception management...
```

and now Exception is thrown!